# How to simplify $(1-\tan^4θ) \cos^2θ+\tan^2θ=$?

Tags: trigonometry

> How to simplify:(change tan.cos into sec .cot or others to make this formula shorter)
>   $$
> (1-\tan^4θ)\cos^2θ+\tan^2θ=?
> $$

I have an answer, but I'm not sure if it is correct. 
$$
\begin{split}
(1-\tan^4θ)\cos^2θ+\tan^2θ
&=(1-\tan^2θ) (1+\tan^2θ)\cos^2θ + \tan^2θ \\
&= \sec^2θ*(1+\tan^2θ)*\cos^2θ + \tan^2θ \\
&=1+\tan^2θ+ \tan^2θ \\
&=1+2\tan^2θ
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "calculate into numbers"? Do you mean, evaluate the expression at a given value of $x$, similar to how a calculator might? You can edit your question to give more detail. Perhaps an example with a simpler function.

Comment: Now that you have edited your post to have it be $(1-\tan^4(\theta))\color{red}{\times}\cos^2(\theta)+\tan^2(\theta)$ as compared to where the red $\times$ was replaced by exponentiation, yes the expression does simplify nicely, and does simplify to $1$.  Your original post where it had exponentiation had no such nice simplification.

Comment: As an aside, in your attempt, you made the substitution $(1-\tan^2(\theta))\mapsto \sec^2(\theta)$.  This is incorrect.  Instead what is true is that $(1\color{red}{+}\tan^2(\theta))=\sec^2(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

You get
$$
\begin{split}
\left(1-\tan^4 x\right)\cos^2x+\tan^2 x
&= \left(1-\tan^2 x\right)\left(1+\tan^2 x\right) \cos^2x+\tan^2 x \\
&= \left(1-\tan^2 x\right)\sec^2 x \cos^2x+\tan^2 x \\
&= \left(1-\tan^2 x\right) + \tan^2 x \\
&= 1.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

we can express all by $\cos(x)$

$${\frac {1}{ \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}} \left( 
 \left( {\frac {2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-1}{
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}}} \right) ^{ \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}} \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+1- \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }
$$

Comment: The post has since been edited to a much more manageable expression which doesn't involve exponentiation by trigonometric functions making this no longer relevant.